# How to add SecIdentityRef to iOS keychain,swift

Tags: ios, swift, certificate, keychain

I am reading a `p12` file and obtaining a `SecIdentityRef` and then add this Identity to keychain as follows

```
let certData: NSData = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(filePath)!
let passDictionary: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
passDictionary.setValue("pass", forKey: kSecImportExportPassphrase as String)
print(kSecImportExportPassphrase as String)
var items: CFArray?
let error = SecPKCS12Import(certData, passDictionary, &items)
let unwrappedItems:CFArray = items!
if error == noErr && CFArrayGetCount(items) > 0 {
    let certChain = unwrappedItems as [AnyObject] as NSArray
    let certificateDict = certChain.objectAtIndex(0)
    var privateKeyRef : SecKeyRef? = nil
    var certificateRef: SecCertificate? = nil
    let secIdentity:SecIdentityRef = certificateDict.valueForKey(kSecImportItemIdentity as String) as! SecIdentityRef
    let subject:NSString=SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certificateRef!)

    let keyChainQuery:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(
        objects: [String(kSecClassIdentity),subject,kCFBooleanTrue,String(kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly),secIdentity],
        forKeys: [String(kSecClass),String(kSecAttrLabel), String(kSecAttrCanSign),String(kSecAttrAccessible),String(kSecValueRef)])
    let status:OSStatus = SecItemAdd(keyChainQuery as CFDictionaryRef, nil)
}
```

This seems to work fine and returns 0 as status code, but when I try to read this item from the keychain:

```
var identity: AnyObject?
let searchQuery: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [String(kSecClassIdentity), kCFBooleanTrue], forKeys: [String(kSecClass),String(kSecReturnRef)])
let status:OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(searchQuery as CFDictionaryRef, &identity)
```

I receive a **-25300 error code (not found item)** and `nil` in identity, I am using `iOS 9.1` as base SDK, what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Tested in 8.1,8.4 and 9.1 simulators and in 9.1 real device, code is working. It's failing with an iPhone with version 8.4.1, anybody have an idea of what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally reinstalling the app and cleaning keychain with SecItemDelete solved the problem.

Hope this helps!!